# how to redirect to another page in same window in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am creating an application in which i am using image  transitions slideshow. in image slideshow i used hyperlink to go another page. but page open in new window. i want page open in same window.

```
flashyslideshow.prototype.getSlideHTML=function (index) {
    var slideHTML= (this.imagearray[index][1])?'<a href=  "' + this.imagearray[index][1]+'" target = "'+this.imagearray[index][2]+ "_self" '">\n' : ''; //hyperlink slide?
    slideHTML+='<img src="'+this.imagearray[index][0]+'" height="550" width="100%" >';
    slideHTML+=(this.imagearray[index][1])? '</a><br />' : '<br />';
    slideHTML+=(this.imagearray[index][3])? '<font face="bookman old style" color="blue" size="3">' + this.imagearray[index][3] : ''; //text description?
    return slideHTML; //return HTML for the slide at the specified index
}
```

Comment: avoid the `target` property and it will load in the same window

Comment: Check this: target = "'+this.imagearray[index][2]+ "_self" '", it's not correct. Why don't you simply use target='_self' (or nothing)?

Comment: This is exactly one of those cases against ? : . People seem to hate if statements and avoid them whenever possible, however in this case it would make your code look a lot less messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `<a>` tag, add

```
target="_self"
```

This forces the link to open in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_self">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by making sure that target is empty, something like this

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="index.html">
```